# Session values becomes null after submitting form in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am working in wordpress. And I am submitting form using javascript. My javascript code to submit the form.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
window.submitpassengerdetail = function() {
    var form;
    form = document.createElement("form"); // CREATE A NEW FORM TO DUMP ELEMENTS INTO FOR SUBMISSION
    form.method = "post"; // CHOOSE FORM SUBMISSION METHOD, "GET" OR "POST"
    form.action = "<?php echo get_permalink(346);?>"; // TELL THE FORM WHAT PAGE TO SUBMIT TO
    jQuery(".details-passenger").children().each(function () { // GRAB ALL CHILD ELEMENTS OF <TD>'S IN THE ROW IDENTIFIED BY idRow, CLONE THEM, AND DUMP THEM IN OUR FORM
        $(this).clone().appendTo(form);
    });
    form.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit(); // NOW SUBMIT THE FORM THAT WE'VE JUST CREATED AND POPULATED
}

});
```

After submitting the form to `get_permalink(346)` I get the session value null set in previous page that is before submitting the form. Session is set but values becomes null. What could be the reason. Thank you.

Comment: where did you append the form to the page?

Comment: I didnot get you.